# How to use same classes in different windows forms?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am working on something in which i have 3 forms first form have two buttons which will take me to other two forms. 
I did that already but my question is now i want to use the classes i made on form1 in other two forms.The classes i am using have simple private string variables and getter setters.

```
 class class_1
    {
        private string n;
        private string f;
        private string a;


        public void setn(string n) { n = n; }
        public void setf(string f) { f = f; }
        public void seta(string a) {a = a; }


        public string getn() { return n; }
        public string getf() { return f; }
        public string geta() { return a; }

    }
```

Comment: Is class_1 in a separate class file? Simply declare it as public class_1 and will be able to use in it any winform.

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning in the question the classes are actually in form 1

Comment: You may declare your class as static, or may pass them as parameter to other forms.

Comment: Ok.. no problem. Simply right click on the WinForm project, select add new item and choose class. change this to be the same as the content of the class in your form and then remove the one on the form namespace

Comment: Do you mean the classes are defined in the code for Form1? Also, edit te question to include that.

Comment: Do you want to use new instances of your class in the other forms or do you want to use the same instance in all forms?

Comment: Also, you may want to define the classes as `public class class_1` so they can be seen outside of Form1

Comment: I want to create new instances on other forms and use them their and yes the code is in the form1 cs. And also there are 2 classes with inheritence

Comment: @Wheels73 if i make the classes like this as u said will they work on all the forms?

Comment: Of course. if you declare them as public.

Comment: You may used like this after declaring class_1 as public:
 
`class_1 myClass = new class_1();
Form2 myForm2 = new Form2(class_1);`

Comment: As a side note, C# uses properties and not setters and getters.  Also, you should use typical C# naming conventions as well (class names and public members should be capitalized).

Comment: @Wheels73 Thank you so much it worked :)

Comment: @AhsanAli - Np.. i'll post an answer if that's ok for a vote?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed, Simply right click on the WinForm project, select add new item and choose class. Change this to be the same as the content of the class in your form and then remove the one on the form namespace. Remember to make it public

```
public class class_1
    {
        private string n;
        private string f;
        private string a;


        public void setn(string n) { n = n; }
        public void setf(string f) { f = f; }
        public void seta(string a) {a = a; }


        public string getn() { return n; }
        public string getf() { return f; }
        public string geta() { return a; }

    }
```

Just a tip. I assume you are just learning but its good practice to name your classes accordingly. Don't leave it as class_1

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just create object of class_1 in your form1 and form2

like

```
class_1 obj = new class_1();
```

And then you'll be able to access property like

```
string temp = obj.getn;
```

And you don't have to create different getter setter,

**c# has properties for that** your code could be

```
class class_1
{
    public string n { get; set; }
    public string f { get; set; }
    public string a { get; set; }
}
```

And that's same thing